Cannot react localhost when running a docker container, but I am currently querying data
I am trying to use local-db and to use for my API image, but when i put the .env that has the URL string it gives me error that:
Error: PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`3306`.
    at /app/index.js:58:11

So I pulled the image from dockerhub and then passing the .env with MySQL string URL
.env file :
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@localhost:3306/database

Procedure:

docker pull user/image
docker run -p 4500:4500 --env-file .env --name container --restart always -d image

However I am accessing the database on localhost on my workbench and querying data.

The localhost from the container is the container itself, in this case, your user/image. You need to point to the mysql container. Might want to look into docker compose to simplify things

@FirstOne Sorry I did not get, how can I fix that?
Both the container and MySQL are run locally.

@Illyrian consider your container to be a separate computer. When you run something in a container, then the localhost is the container, not the computer on which the container runs.

Solution:
use host.docker.internal instead of localhost
Env should be like this if you use localhost:
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@host.docker.internal:3306/database

